# Hints for title line breaks in Plone

Tags: html, css, plone, line-breaks

Does HTML support any kind of hinting for (title) line-breaks? The problem is that often page titles or navigational titles have funny line breaking, as they happen to break wherever the current HTML element spacing allows. Manual line-breaks would give much nicer visuals, when line-breaks are needed.

The line-break hints should be something the editor can himself/herself enter to an `<input type=text>` field.

Comment: input[text] doesn't support linebreaks. Also, could you give an example of the current situation and an example of what you want? (a screenshot maybe)

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean line breaks in `title` elements, or in `title` attributes, or in headings (often called “titles,” too), or maybe something else. They are rather different with respect to line breaking issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Please see the answer below.

Comment: If you want to get extreme, you could probably use some js at doc ready to see if the headline has broken to multiple lines. If it has, use newspaper rules (lines should be as close as possible to the same visual length; no overhangs) to insert breaks.

Answer (score 4):

There's the `&shy;` (soft hyphen) entity and the [`<wbr>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-wbr-element) (HTML5) for word break marks. Notice that `&shy;` will create a hyphen if the line breaks, while `<wbr>` won't.

See also http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html.

So an editor could use `&shy;` for word breaking if he prefers a dash (-), or `&#8203;` if he prefers only a word break.

Comment: Now just need an idea how to make <input> to support typing in soft breaks. It's easy to do the proper conversion on the server side, as the users learn somehow to type these with normal keyboard and unicode character set (no arbitrary HTML input)