# Is there an "invisible" hyphen character in Unicode / HTML?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I've found the [soft hyphen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) character (U+00AD SHY) very useful but I am wondering if there is the same thing that will tell the browser where to break long words for wrapping *without* adding any character at all?

For example, let's say you have a narrow column in HTML with newspaper justification and there is a long URL explicitly in the text itself. You could add the soft/shy hyphen I mentioned but then when a user copy and pastes the URL it will contain those dash characters. An ideal situation would be the same visual results *without* a hyphen character so that the user may copy and paste the long word(s).

Thoughts or suggestions?

I tried searching for this but most of what I come up with is non-breaking space characters and essentially I am looking for the opposite.

**UPDATE**: I found the [ZERO-WIDTH SPACE](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) (U+200B) *but* it still has the problem that the character is preserved during copy&paste into the address bar so the results are even more confusing to the end user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hints for title line breaks in Plone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276606/hints-for-title-line-breaks-in-plone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the HTML5 tag [`<wbr>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-wbr-element), which is specified to do exactly what you are asking for.

If you can't rely on HTML5, U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE (`&#8203;`) should also work.

(The effects of copying text out of an HTML document, unfortunately, are underspecified.  If `<wbr>` doesn't do what you want upon copy-and-paste, you might want to bring it up to the WhatWG — the easiest way to do that is probably to [file a Github issue on the spec](https://whatwg.org/newbug).)

Comment: In Chrome, the <wbr> did not cause any additional characters to be copied! Excellent ... here I was looking for a Unicode character and HTML5 solved it with a special tag!